# How to remove elevation shadow from one side without removing elevation itself in flutter from Card or Material widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, elevation, card

How can I remove top-side elevation shadow inside Card or Material widget.

I used Material widget to container and given a value for elevation. it reflects to my container in all side. But i want only left, bottom and right side elevation shadow. how can i get it or remove top side elevation shadow.
Example from  Material or Card Widget will be useful.

```dart
Material(
  elevation: 3,
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 300,
  ),
)
```

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Do add some code

Comment: You can achieve this by giving shadow to a container

Comment: I was trying to achieve it using Material or Card widget.

Comment: Add some code here

Comment: Material( elevation: 3, child: Container( height: 100, width: 100, ), )
removing elevation from top side will be helpful.

Comment: Brother, just add the part of the code that want to be edited

Comment: `Material( elevation: 3, child: Container( height: 100, width: 100, ), )`

Comment: mycode is too long brother.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that, you just have to bring the `shadow` a little bit down by increasing the *y-axis* of the `offset` property just like this:

```
Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 300.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          spreadRadius: 2,
          blurRadius: 3,
          offset: Offset(0, 6),
          color: Colors.black38
        )
      ]
    ),
  ),
```

Here's the output:

[image]